# C# VisualStudio 2015 how to use code from existing solution in to the new solution

Tags: visual-studio, c#-4.0

I am creating a new project in c# visual studio 2015. I want to use some codes from couple of existing solutions. How to approach this situation in a best way?
I have never worked on multiple solutions in VS2015 before.

Appreciate some inputs.

I am trying to follow the below link:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/habibh/2009/06/25/walkthrough-adding-an-existing-visual-studio-solution-to-another-solution/

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A solution is made up of one or more projects.  You should aim to structure your code in to projects that each provide a set of cohesive functionality, which can then be re-used in multiple scenarios.

All you then have to do in your new solution is to say `Add -> Existing Project ...` and browse to it.

If you're not quite structured enough for that at this point then you can always create a new project, and within the project say `Add -> Existing Item` and include existing individual files, but if you're doing that then I would recommend selecting the `Include As Link` checkbox in the browse dialog, so that you are not making a copy, just referring to the original file.

Answer (score 0):

in a solution you can add many project. Just add old projects to new solution